# How to publish and keep multiple versions of an React Native app installed?

Tags: react-native, google-play, app-store

I am in need of advice of how to deal with something:

I have an app that will soon be published to App Store and Google Play, I would like to find a way to have a clone of this app with less features, this clone is meant to give a taste of the app for users and also for the salesman of the company to demonstrate it, also I would like to keep both apps installed in the same device, so in the case of the salesman, they could demonstrate with this "demo app" and also use the real app for their own purposes.

I know that I could just have a beta user group on TestFlight and Google Play but that would need me to register those users or give them a link to register as beta and would not be possible to have both apps installed.

I want to make this "demonstration app" to be downloadable from the stores, it would have different API calls from the real app, different icon, etc... 
 but I would like to avoid having to maintain and copying every change from the "production" app to the "demo" app.

The option I thought: create a branch and rename the app to the new signature, name, icons and so I will just have to always pull the diff from the origin/master branch and publish it on the stores, but it didn't worked, since xcode breaks the app and give me random errors when I do it.

I would appreciate to receive ideas and workarounds for this.

Comment: Use product flavours I have around 45 flavours of it in combination with this library - https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config

Comment: @AshwinMothilal I am gonna take a look at it, with flavours you mean like a different version of the app? Because this app I am working on will work like a template for other apps just changing api and theme.

Comment: Yeah it's like white labelling apps, different appId, icon, splash, theme, api and if required some custom stuff. Everything should have different appId for them to exist with the original App.

Answer (score 4):

I can currently have four different versions of an app I developed installed. The solution for this really depends on your setup, but here is currently how I do it<sup>1</sup>. It is not the only way but it works for me and I find the *issues* that this setup causes so small that it doesn't really bother me.

## iOS

The simplest solution for `iOS` is to have different `Bundle Identifiers`. This requires you to have different provisioning profiles. One provisioning profile for each development environment (if you want to put them on device for testing away from the development machine they need to be *distribution* profiles) and one profile for submission to the App Store.

Xcode has the ability to manage different environments with different provisioning profiles, however this caused me major issues when using CocoaPods and I ended up having to stop Xcode from managing it.

What I do now is I add a script to my workflow<sup>2</sup> that forces the correct Bundle Identifier for the environment. If I want to build locally, I just manually change the Bundle Identifier and the provisioning profile (it only takes a second)

## Android

For `Android` I use the built in `flavors` to manage the different environments. It is really easy to set up. in my `app/build.gradle` I added the following:

```
flavorDimensions "version"
productFlavors {
    dev {
        dimension "version"
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
    }
    uat {
        dimension "version"
        applicationIdSuffix ".uat"
    }
    staging {
        dimension "version"
        applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
    }
    prod {
        dimension "version"
        applicationIdSuffix ".prod"
    }
}
```

This adds a `applicationIdSuffix` to your builds which means that you can install multiple types on to your device. Using flavors is a really powerful way to manage your android applications. You can read more about using flavors [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)

One important point to note is that using flavors does change how you have to run your application.

Instead of using `react-native run-android` I now have to use `react-native run-android --variant=devDebug`.

When I want to build it instead of using `./gradlew assembleRelease`, I have to use `./gradlew assembledevRelease` (you have to change this for each *flavor* that you use)

There is also a small bug with react-native that when using the `--variant` flag it doesn't launch the app, so you just have to click on the icon on the device. But if you launch it from `Android Studio` it launches just fine.

So if you launch your application from `Android Studio`, or add the appropriate scripts to your `package.json` these issues melt away.

---

<sup>1</sup> I don't use Expo for my production applications, only for prototyping, so these solutions are for full `react-native` applications **with access** to native code.

<sup>2</sup> I use Bitrise to build my apps so it is easy to add bash scripts or similar to the build process.

Comment: It's a way to go while I don't have like 3-4 versions of the app, it will work like a template in future.

How do you publish with the .beta signature? Because on iOS when I select Archive it just sends release version.

Comment: When you create an archive in `iOS` it will always select the *release* version. As I said in my answer you will need to change the bundle id  and use the appropriate provisioning profile for your beta version so that when you archive it uses the correct details for your build. As I use Bitrise to make my builds I have settings and scripts that make the changes for me. Locally I just manually change the settings in Xcode.

Comment: I see, I am planning to use Fastlane in future because of the price of Bitrise. Thank you for your answer

Comment: This approach needs extra caution if one is using Firebase for messaging or auth.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to download the apps from stores then **apps have to have different package/applicationIDs**.

I've worked on a `react native` project recently and we actually handled `staging` and `production` apps in single branch. Although we didn't release `staging` app on play store, we were sharing using `Google drive` and since both app had different packages, it was possible to install both of them together.

To change the `applicationId`, you need to make changes in app's `build.gradle` file in `Android`. Simply add `.demo` or `.anything` at the end of your production `applicationId`. And also change your api end point and App name and icons if you'd like. So this becomes cumbersome doing manually after sometime because you have to change back and forth. So we wrote a `shell script` to make all these changes before building the `apk`.

We actually didn't need to install 2 versions on iPhone, so we didn't do anything about it. Also I'm not familiar with iOS development but I guess process will be somewhat similar.

Now we don't have to keep track of changes from one branch to another. Setup(`Shell scripts`) will take some but it will be worth it.